# Eclipse Refactor Project into executable and library

Tags: c, eclipse, refactoring

I have an Eclipse project that is currently a monolithic one. That is, it contains all of the C source/includes and build an executable. This project is comprised of a GIT module and several submodules. I would like to refactor this Eclipse PROJECT so that it contains the executable project and projects for the submodules as static libraries.

I'm pretty sure that I can do this if I was creating this from scratch. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do this by modifying the existing project.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Create new projects as you would from scratch and add the corresponding sources.

Comment: After reviewing you answer and trying a few approaches, I have a few questions for you.

When I add the new project ("new makefile project from existing source", "New C Makefile project", or "Import whatever") the resulting project will not build. I get the dreaded "Nothing to be done for ".  I've been through the setting multiple times, googled a solution, fiddled with every option, but nothing has succeeded in building this.


What other words of wisdom might you have for me?